# Django-star-ratings: Calculating average ratings from different model

Tags: django

I've got two models:

```
class Series(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=140, unique=True)

class Issue(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm using django-star-ratings to allow the user to rate the individual issues. I'd like to get an average rating for the series based on the issues that have been rated, but haven't been able to come up with a decent solution after reading the documentation.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you post how you proceeded?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking for here. Are you wondering how I implemented the issue ratings? Or what progress I'm making on solving this? If it's the second, I'm currently working on adding a property to the Series model's that uses a for loop with it's issue_set to query the Rating model object_id.

Comment: I never use `django-star-rating` before, but after reading the doc, to get an average for something from `django-star-rating`, a property method inside the `Issue` class will do the trick. if I miss the point, just show me your property method, definitely it should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that I've come up with:

On the Series model, I've added the following:

```
    @property
    def average_rating(self):
        l = []
        for issue in self.issue_set.all():
            l.append(issue.id)

        rating = Rating.objects.filter(object_id__in=l).aggregate(Avg('average'))

        return rating['average__avg']
```

If anyone has a better solution, please don't be shy about sharing it.